Error Draft of Knowledge Article wasn't deleted. Try again. happens when user tries to delete a draft article
When One user creates and published an article and then another user is editing this article as a draft (creates a new Draft Version), this user is unable to delete a draft article version created.
Only the user who originally created the published version can delete the new draft version or an admin.
Why such behavior is present? Is this internal salesforce bug?

The problem is that when a new draft version is created, the new user is not owner of it but the owner of the original version.
If we create a trigger before insert to set the OwnerId to the current user, it works fine.
Another approach would be to create a Queue with both users and assign the article and all its versions to the queue
